# having trouble getting a moving image disappear on click

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't know what I'm doing.  I'm trying to learn JS and it's been touch and go from the start.  I would like to  make a floating image disappear once it is clicked.  I don't think my code is correct.  Any comments or words of advise would be helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Mario

This is what I am using to make the image to disappear:

```
 function mousePressed(){
   if(dist(pagex, pageY, chip.xx, chip.yy) < chip/1){
     chip=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mario, can you include the HTML that goes with the code snippet? Any where are pageX, pageY, and chip referring to?

Comment: Looks like there is some code missing in your question... Maybe only due to formatting. Anyhow: how about adding a click listener to the image and inside that listener just set the display property of the `event.target` property to none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably you should use [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) on the HTML element as it will run your code when clicking directly on the element. No need to check coordinates manually.

The image can be hidden by setting the CSS property [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to `none`.

See this example:

```js
function hideMe(element){
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" onclick="hideMe(this);">
```

Comment: You should edit your original question and add the code there, preferably as a runnable snippet.